# Un-Normalise Data Frame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have a data frame which I normalise to put in a algorithm. After the algorithm runs, I get a series of normalised predicted values. I want to un-normalise these values to put on a post processing calculus. To normalise I use the MinMax Scaler. How can I properly un-normalise these values?

Data normalisation:

```
# normalise data
df_scaled = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(df.values)
dfx_scaled = pd.DataFrame(df_scaled, columns=df.columns)
```

The predicted values have the form of an array:

```
# predicted array of values
array([[0.25426427],
       [0.00605401],
       [0.60834366],
       [0.21384366],
       [0.16588062],
       [0.25884567]])
```

I thought about multiplying the predicted values by the max value of the column target before normalisation but I don't think that is correct.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: just take the inverse function if the norm `y = (x-min)/(max-min)` then `x = y*(max-min)+min`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transformers in sklearn have an `inverse_transform` method that does that. However you seem to do the normalization of features & target together so that can't be utilized as is. Therefore you can separate these:

```
# prepare two scalers
X_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
y_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()

# features are everything but target
X = df.drop(columns="target")
y = df["target"]

# scale them separately
X_scaled = X_scaler.fit_transform(X)
y_scaled = y_scaler.fit_transform(y)

# training..
# ...

# prediction time
preds = ...
unnormalized_preds = y_scaler.inverse_transform(preds)
```

Comment: also noting that scaling of training & test data shouldn't be done together but that's not the main focus of the question I believe.

Comment: if there are multiple targets, I should normalise together right? only separate from the other data

Comment: @Peter Yes, exactly.

Comment: For example, in my implementation I have two targets, is the process the same as represented above? The unnormalization with the inverse transform?

Comment: @Peter Yes, the scaler (e.g., `y_scaler`) remembers the min/max values and the shape it transformed so the `inverse_transform` works for multiple targets, too.